# Trying to understand userSchema password encryption with Monggoose

Tags: mongoose, cryptojs

I am a complete beginner and I run to my teacher's code where in we are trying to encrypt the password first before finally saving it to the database.

Here's the code after the userSchema:

```
userSchema
  .virtual("password")
  .set(function (password) {
    // create a temporary variable called _password
    this._password = password;
    // generate salt
    this.salt = this.makeSalt();
    // encryptPassword
    this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
  })
  .get(function () {
    return this._password;
  });

userSchema.methods = {
  authenticate: function (plainText) {
    return this.encryptPassword(plainText) == this.hashed_password;
  },

  encryptPassword: function (password) {
    if (!password) return "";
    try {
      return crypto.createHmac("sha1", this.salt).update(password).digest("hex");
    } catch (err) {
      return "";
    }
  },

  makeSalt: function () {
    return Math.round(new Date().valueOf() * Math.random() + "");
  },
};
```

I know this might be too much but can anyone explain to me how does these lines of codes work in the encryption in layman's term? I would appreciate if anyone can help a student like me understand this..\

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

authenticate : This method is called to verify sign-in attempts by
matching the user-provided password text with the hashed_password
stored in the database for a specific user.

encryptPassword : This method is used to generate an encrypted hash
from the plain-text password and a unique salt value using the crypto
module from Node.

makeSalt : This method generates a unique and random salt value using
the current timestamp at execution and Math.random() .

The crypto module provides a range of cryptographic
functionality, including some standard cryptographic hashing
algorithms. In our code, we use the SHA1 hashing algorithm
and createHmac from crypto to generate the cryptographic
HMAC hash from the password text and salt pair.
Hashing algorithms generate the same hash for the same input
value. But to ensure two users don't end up with the same hashed
password if they happen to use the same password text, we pair
each password with a unique salt value before generating the
hashed password for each user. This will also make it difficult to
guess the hashing algorithm being used because the same user input
is seemingly generating different hashes.